# Почему не срабатывает привязка к свойству Text в WPF & materialdesign

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

не подтягивается свойство от элемента ipUdBase к элементу whobase2

```xaml
<materialDesign:Flipper.BackContent>
    <Grid Height="256" Width="300">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <materialDesign:ColorZone Mode="Accent" Padding="6">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignToolForegroundButton}" Command="{x:Static materialDesign:Flipper.FlipCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ArrowLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                </Button>
                <TextBlock Margin="8 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center">Ввести данные</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:ColorZone>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0 6 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox x:Name="ipUdBase" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="ip адресс базы" materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="True" Margin="0 12 0 0" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="whoBase2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ElementName=ipUdBase, Path=Text, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</materialDesign:Flipper.BackContent>
```

Comment: после ввода текста в поле ipUdBase - не появляется такой же текст в whoBase2

Comment: А где код? И вот вы скажите, вам нравиться такое форматирование? Будто нагадили тут и просите еще помощи, не уж то нельзя оформить как положено?

Comment: сорри за формат, но так это и есть код разметки

Comment: пробовал так же добавить привязку через код - InitializeComponent();
            Binding binding = new Binding();

            binding.ElementName = "ipUdBase"; // элемент-источник
            binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Text"); // свойство элемента-источника
            whoBase2.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);

Comment: Это разметка, не код. Где C# код, в котором есть класс, который установлен как `DataContext`, в котором есть публичное свойство `ipUdBase` к которому вы пытаетесь привязать XAML?

Comment: когда делаю привязку таким образом не во флиппере, а просто в новой вкладке - то всё привязывается

Comment: в новом табе вставляю код <StackPanel>
                                                                <TextBox x:Name="ipUdBase" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="ip адресс базы" materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="True"
                                     Margin="0 12 0 0" />
                                                                <TextBlock x:Name="whoBase2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ElementName=ipUdBase, Path=Text, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
                                                                </StackPanel>

Comment: Я рад, что у вас все привязывается. Вы либо делаете минимальный, самодостаточный пример, который мы сможет проверить у себя, либо пытайтесь разобраться сами. Дальнейшие обсуждения бессмысленны, ибо вы кидаете совершенно невнятный код, который совершенно не о чем не говорит. P.S. Код кидайте в вопрос, нажав "править" под ним.

Comment: проблема именно во флиппере материалдизайна, во всех других родительских элементах данная привязка работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так.

```xaml
<TextBox x:Name="ipUdBase" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="ip адресс базы" materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="True" Margin="0 12 0 0" />
<TextBlock x:Name="whoBase2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=ipUdBase}" />
```

Не знаю, что в вашем случае произошло, но у меня безотказно работает следующий пример.

Кстати, не получилось ли так, что контролы мешают друг другу? Попробуйте `StackPanel`, или в разные `Grid.Row` их поместите.

```csharp
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=MyTextBox}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

---

Ну или если предположить что `Binding` здесь не работает по какой-то непонятной причине, то можно попробовать решить через обработчик события `TextChanged`

```xaml
<TextBox x:Name="ipUdBase" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="ip адресс базы" materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="True" Margin="0 12 0 0" TextChanged="ipUdBase_TextChanged"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="whoBase2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

```csharp
private void ipUdBase_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    whoBase2.Text = (sender as TextBox).Text;
}
```

Comment: так тоже не срабатывает

Comment: @АрхиповВладимир с обычными контролами работает, обновил ответ, прошу прощения за ошибку.

Comment: да, с обычными контролами работает, не работает именно во флиппере гугл материал дизайна, пробовал в стэкпэнел заварачивать - не помогает.

Comment: @АрхиповВладимир а вы пробовали по старинке без биндингов с обработчиком события `TextChanged`?

Comment: да, по событию всё работает как положено, наверное так и придётся делать во флиппере

Comment: @АрхиповВладимир дополнил ответ.